# Why does the HttpExchange (declarative HttpClient) in Spring 6 use Jackson when trying to send multipart form-data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

i am trying to implement a REST API client using the new declarative HttpClient in Spring 6.

I have defined my client like that:

```java
@HttpExchange(
        url = "/publicapi",
        contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        accept = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE
)
public interface MyClient {
    @PostExchange(url = "/submit/file",
                  contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(@RequestPart String apiKey,
                                    @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file);
}
```

Then i have declared a Bean for that client:

```java
    @Bean
    MyClient myClient(MyClientProperties properties) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(properties.getUrl())
                .defaultStatusHandler(
                        httpStatusCode -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == httpStatusCode,
                        response -> Mono.empty())
                .defaultStatusHandler(
                        HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError,
                        response -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("WildfireClient request failed. Code: " + response.statusCode().value())))
                .build();

        return HttpServiceProxyFactory
                .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
                .build()
                .createClient(MyClient.class);
    }
```

And then i am trying to use the client to upload a file from Google Cloud Storage:

```java
...
        try (ReadChannel reader = storage.reader(blobId)) {
            var inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(reader);

            MultipartFile file = new MultipartFile() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return webhookRequest.name();
                }

                @Override
                public String getOriginalFilename() {
                    return webhookRequest.name();
                }

                @Override
                public String getContentType() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEmpty() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public long getSize() {
                    return webhookRequest.size();
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
                    return FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
                }

                @Override
                public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                    return inputStream;
                }

                @Override
                public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
                    FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, Files.newOutputStream(dest.toPath()));
                }
            };

            myClient.submitFile(wildfireApiKey, file);
```

But something strange happens. I get an error that Jackson cannot encode the value:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:256) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:158) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
...
```

Why is Jackson involved here? The body of the request should be multipart form data. So no JSON conversion should be done here...

I halso have tried to implement it via manual WebClient instantiation and that worked without problems. But i really want to use the new declarative client.

Comment: Multipart isn't supported yet, it will be as of Sprng 6.1, so probably Spring Boot 3.2.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh, then it makes sense... Do you have a source for that statement?

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/e69a1d22f97f2907260cd9b992eb113700abf193) which was made 5 hours ago. It adds `Multipart` support to the http client.

Comment: What a timing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipart support isn't possible yet, or at least `MultipartFile` support hasn't been added. See [this enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/30728) which will add.

Support has been added with [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/e69a1d22f97f2907260cd9b992eb113700abf193), so it appears as it will be part of Spring Framework 6.1 and therefor probably Spring Boot 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

@M.Deinum is right. Multipart support isn't possible in Spring Boot versions below 3.2

I resolved this by following [the commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/e69a1d22f97f2907260cd9b992eb113700abf193) that is supposed to solve this in Spring Boot 3.2, then I replicated it in my project which is using **Spring Boot 3.0.1**

So what they did was to introduce a

> MultipartFileArgumentResolver

Below is my HttpClient configuration and how I adapted it to the solution in Spring Boot 3.2

*PS: I am using Spring Security hence the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager on my Webclient*

Before:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2ClientConfig { 

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;
    private final ApplicationConfigurations applicationConfigurations;
    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager() {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
                    .builder()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, clientService);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(applicationConfigurations.getServiceDiscovery().getGatewayService())
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector())
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    GatewayServiceConnectorClient gatewayServiceConnectorClient() {
        HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
            .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient(authorizedClientManager())))
            .build();
    return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(GatewayServiceConnectorClient.class);
    }

}
```

After:

Simply add the *MultipartFileArgumentResolver* class to your project and import the necessary packages.

```
public class MultipartFileArgumentResolver extends AbstractNamedValueArgumentResolver {

    private static final String MULTIPART_FILE_LABEL = "multipart file";

    @Override
    protected NamedValueInfo createNamedValueInfo(MethodParameter parameter) {
        if (!parameter.nestedIfOptional().getNestedParameterType().equals(MultipartFile.class)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new NamedValueInfo("", true, null, MULTIPART_FILE_LABEL, true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void addRequestValue(@NotNull String name, @NotNull Object value, @NotNull MethodParameter parameter,
                                   HttpRequestValues.Builder requestValues) {
        Assert.state(value instanceof MultipartFile,
                     "The value has to be of type 'MultipartFile'");

        MultipartFile file = (MultipartFile) value;
        requestValues.addRequestPart(name, toHttpEntity(name, file));
    }

    private HttpEntity<Resource> toHttpEntity(String name, MultipartFile file) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        if (file.getOriginalFilename() != null) {
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(name, file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        if (file.getContentType() != null) {
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, file.getContentType());
        }
        return new HttpEntity<>(file.getResource(), headers);
    }
}
```

then add it to your HttpClient interface proxy using the already available *customArgumentResolver()* method.

```
@Bean
GatewayServiceConnectorClient gatewayServiceConnectorClient() {
     HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
                .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient(authorizedClientManager())))
                .customArgumentResolver(new MultipartFileArgumentResolver())
                .build();
     return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(GatewayServiceConnectorClient.class);
 }
```

then finally in your HttpClient definition.

```
@HttpExchange
public interface GatewayServiceConnectorClient {
     @PostExchange(value = "/upload", contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> uploadFacilities(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file);
}
```

And Voila!